# Hidden Eggs Puzzle 20|20

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, seasonal

## Whodunnit?

[image: eggs]

#twinning

---

For accessibility, the following is a transcription of the colors. The colors of each egg (b/p/y) from top to bottom are listed in each string. Eggs in a row are separated by spaces, and rows of eggs are separated by newlines.

```
bpybypb pybypby bpypyby pbypybp ypbpypy pybpypy pypbpyb ypybpyp bpbypyp pbypbpb pypbybp pypbpyp bypbypb ypbpbpb ybypbpy pbpbypb pybybyp ypbpbyp pybybpb bypbpby ypbybyb pbpybyp ybpbybp ypbypyp bpybpyp ybybpby pybpypb ybybpbp bypybyb ybybpby
ybpypby ybpbypb bpypypb pbpypby pybypby ybpbpbp ybpypyp bypbypy ypybybp bpypbyp pbpbypy pbpbpyp bybpbpb pypbpbp pypbpyp pybypyp ypbybpy bpbpybp pbpypbp pybybyp pbpybpb pbypyby ypybypb ybpbpby ypypbpy ypbypbp bybybpb pbpbpbp ypypbyb ybpybyp
ybpybyb bybpybp ybpypbp bybybyb ybybybp pypypby ypbypyb bybypyp ybybypb pypbpby pbpbyby bypbybp ypybpbp ypybyby bpbpypy pybypbp ybypbpb ypybpby pbypypb pypbypb ybybypy bpbybyp pbypbpy bpybyby ybypbyp ypypypy pbpypyp ypbybpb pypypyb ybpbpyp
pypybyp ybybybp ypybpyb bypypby bpybpbp bpybpby pypybpb ypbpbyb bpypybp bypybyp pybpbpy ypybypy bpbpypy pbybpbp ybpbypy pbypbyp bybybpy pypbypb bpypbpb pbpybyb bpybybp pypbypy ybpybpy ybybyby pbpbpyb bypybpb bpbypby ybpypyb pypybyb ypypbyp
bpybpyb pypypbp ypypbpb ypbpyby bypbpyb pbybpyb bpypbpy bybpbyp bpypbpy bpbypbp pypybpy pbybpby pybpbpb bpbpypb ypybypy pbybypy bypbpyp bpbpbyb ypbypby bybybpy bypybpy bybybyp ybypybp ybypypy bybpbpy ypypybp bpbybyb pybpyby bpybypy bybpypb
pypbyby pybpybp bypbyby bypbpbp pybpbyp bpypypy bybpypy bypypyp ypbpbpy ybpbyby pbybpyp pbpypyb bypypyb bybypyb bpbpbpy ypbpypb pybypyb ybypyby bpbpbpb ybybpyb ybypypb ypypyby ypbybyp pybybyb ybybpyp pbybypb bpbpyby bpbypyb ybpybpb bybpbyb
bpybypb ybpbpyb pbpybpy pybybpy pypypbp ypybpyp bybypbp ypbpybp pbpbpby bypbypy pypbybp bpbpbpy ypypypb bpypbyb pbypypy pbpbypb ybybpyb pybpbyb bypypbp bybpyby pbypbyb ybypbyb ybpbybp pbpbybp bybypby bpbybpb bpbpbyp ybybpbp pypypyp pbybyby
```

<sup>Happy Easter!</sup>

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide a transcription of the colors here?

Comment: @Deusovi To accommodate accessibility (e.g., for visual impairments) or to enable the use of computers (e.g., for searching)? The latter should not be required, so I hesitate to provide a transcript if it's not necessary. (I would also advise against solvers going through the trouble of transcribing themselves.)

Comment: Is it [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: @WeatherVane N/A

Comment: @noedne Both. I am colorblind, so the transcription would help that way, but it would also make things less tedious for whatever processing of these eggs is necessary.

Comment: @Deusovi You're right, and I've now added a transcript. I wasn't sure the best way to format it, but I hope it's sufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a nice little Easter puzzle :) It turns out there are:

> **20** pairs of matching Easter eggs in this image. This is hinted at by the hashtag '#twinning' and the use of "20|20" in the title - it doesn't just happen to be the current year but also a nod to how many pairs of eggs there are.
>
>  <sup>(I should admit that I used the supplementary text version to enable me to find them more easily using Excel and a LOT of Ctrl+F...)</sup>

The next thing to do is:

> Notice that for each pair of eggs there isn't ever too much distance between the two matching eggs. There are also several instances where one of the pair occupies the top line and the other occupies the bottom line in the same column. This suggests to me that we might be expected to *draw straight lines linking each pair* and see if this produces an image, akin to a dot-to-dot.

Doing this produces the following:

> [image]

If we are to presume that the question 'Whodunnit?' translates as 'Who has hidden the eggs?', well the answer is now right before our eyes!

> The straight lines appear to spell out the letters of '**RABBIT**'. It's that Easter Bunny again!